# Trabalhar com 'weights' é algo viável?

Tags: android

estou montando um layout aqui e após incluir a propriedade: **android:layout_weight**, o eclipse retorna uma advertência:  'nested weights bad for performance'.

Porque trabalhar com essa propriedade, é ruim para performance? E até que ponto, isso vai influenciar no desempenho/performance?

Obrigado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_codProduto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"     //Advertência aparece aqui
            android:text="Código Produto:" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_descProduto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="Descrição:" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/et_codProduto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"           //Advertência aparece aqui
            android:inputType="none"/>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/et_descProduto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:inputType="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_complemento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Complemento:"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_complemento"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_qtdeEstoque"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"          //Advertência aparece aqui
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Estoque:"
            android:inputType="none"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_vrVenda"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Valor de Venda:"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_qtdeEstoque"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"          //Advertência aparece aqui
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_vrVenda"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:ems="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_fornecedor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Fornecedor:"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/ed_fornecedor"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Se o *Eclipse* retorna com essa advertência é porque de facto é mau para a performance. Não lhe sei explicar porquê. O que posso dizer é que, nos muitos *layouts* que já fiz, poucas vezes tive de utilizar `android:layout_weight` e, que me lembre, nunca de forma "aninhada". O que esta advertência pode sugerir também é que há outras formas de conseguir o mesmo objectivo sem a utilização de *nested weights*. Se você postar o *Xml* do seu *layout* talvez seja mais fácil podermos ajudá-lo. Se não, esta pergunta poderá vir a ser considerada **Ampla de mais**

Comment: @ramaral - Add o xml. Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é ruim porque o `layout_weight` exige que o *widget* seja medido duas vezes quando um `LinearLayout` com *weight* diferente de zero está aninhado em outro `LinearLayout` com *weight* também diferente de zero, isso aumenta exponencialmente as medições.

Uma alternativa é utilizar [`RelativeLayouts`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) e ajustar a exibição de acordo com os lugares de outros *views* , sem o uso de valores [dpi](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontos_por_polegada) específicos.

Referências:

- <sub>[Optimizing Layout Hierarchies](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)</sub>
- <sub>[Why are nested weights bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9430764/1608936)</sub>